# How to validate forms in ruby rails with a function I defined in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I use functions I have defined in the model to validate my form? One functions I have defined will check if the email (using the swot gem) is valid and the other will convert the email to a domain.
The file below is the models/profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    def converttocollegedomain(string)
        domain = ''
        at_count = 0
        for x in string
            if at_count > 0
                domain = domain + c
            end
            if x=='@'
                at_count=at_count+1
            end
        end
        return domain
    end
    def checkemail?
        @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
        dom = converttocollegedomain(user.profile.collegeemail)
        result1 = Swot::is_academic? user.profile.collegeemail  
        result2 = Swot::is_academic? dom 
        result = result1 && result2
        return result
    end
    validates :collegeemail, User.checkemail?
end
```

I expected it to work but it says "undefined method `checkemail?' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did few mistakes. You need to replace `User.checkemail?` to `:checkemail?` since this method is defined in `Profile` model, not in `User`.
When you use a custom method for validation, you should use `validate` instead of `validates`.
No need to do `User.find` in your validator method.
`params[:user_id]` will not work in model, such code can be written only in controllers. In model you don't have `params` variable.

This code should work:

```rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true

  def checkemail?
    if self.collegeemail.present?
      domain = self.collegeemail.split("@").second
      return if Swot::is_academic?(self.collegeemail) || Swot::is_academic?(domain)
    end
    errors.add(:collegeemail, 'not academic email')
  end

  validate :checkemail?
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you why it says split not defined for nill class even though collegeemail is a string.

Comment: Could you please share code of controller and form? Did you allow :collegeemail in `permit`?
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Still the Swot gem does not work though. It is allowing me to enter any email and it accepts that. I entered 'dfs' in the collegeemail field and it allowed that. What can I do?

Comment: Ah, I forgot that `return false` in custom validator will not do the job. You need to call `errors.add` function. I have updated my answer. Please try one more time and check if it works.

Comment: It works for emails with non academic domains by adding a question mark to the function name and removing the underscore from first argument of errors.add. Can I ask you why you did return if and not just return. It does not work random emails like dhshjjgf@harvard.edu as it accepts that. Also, how would I change the code to accept if someone puts no input at all but only verify if it is a collegeemail if they input something

Comment: If inputted data is correct I do early return to skip `errors.add...` (we don't need to add error if data is correct)  

I made a few typos, sorry. I have edited my answer. Please try one more time.

Comment: I use one-line version of if.
https://www.natashatherobot.com/ruby-shorthands-if-then-else/

Comment: This doesnt work as well. I can still enter any email like nonononafdudosfgl@harvard.edu.

Comment: Also, if I have correct input but edit to incorrect input it will give this error:                      missing template profiles/#<Profile:0x007f9ade090698>, application/#<Profile:0x007f9ade090698> with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/ec2-user/environment/saasapp/app/views" * "/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views"

Comment: << I can still enter any email like nonononafdudosfgl@harvard.edu >>

Swot gem can only validate domain names. It's not possible to validate email accounts (text before '@'). Think what will happen when university hires a new employee? University sysadmins create few new email accounts every day. There is a limited amount of universities and their domain names. But amount of email accounts is huge and growing every day.

Comment: << missing template profiles >> This error is not related to Profile model. Something is wrong with controller and templates. Please create a new question on stackoverflow and share code of your controller.